Combine three trained binary classification models into single multiclassification model in keras
I have three trained binary classification models, they are trained with sigmoid activation at output layer.

First model returning probability scalar from 0 to 1 to check whether image is number ZERO or not.
Second model returning probability scalar from 0 to 1 to check whether image is number ONE or not.
Third model returning probability scalar from 0 to 1 to check whether image is number TWO or not.


I know I can just trained them with softmax with constructing model with three neurons at output layer. But suppose I have a situation where it's really take a long time to train their weights due to complex model, all I have just their individual model of binary classification. Or, I want extract their hidden representation features at hidden layer for example model_0 (binary classification to check whether image is number zero or not).
So, how to concat/combine/merge them into single model?
My code currently stuck at this point:
model_0 = init_binary_classification_model((28,28))
model_0.load_weights('trained_weight_of_binary_classification_to_check_whether_image_is_zero.h5')

model_1 = init_binary_classification_model((28,28))
model_1.load_weights('trained_weight_of_binary_classification_to_check_whether_image_is_one.h5')

model_2 = init_binary_classification_model((28,28))
model_2.load_weights('trained_weight_of_binary_classification_to_check_whether_image_is_two.h5')

Where:
def init_binary_classification_model(input_shape=(28,28)):
  input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
  tensor = Flatten()(input_layer)
  tensor = Dense(16, activation='relu')(tensor)
  tensor = Dense(8, activation='relu')(tensor)
  output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(tensor)

  return Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

I expect the multi-classification model has same input shape (28,28) and different output shape (3) and I don't need retrain the model (if possible).
Full code is available at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1y1mvAzebIFU_cuEQo8Q60L1I6uT8i2Ce?usp=sharing

Load trained binary classification models
m0 = init_binary_classification_model(input_shape)
m0.load_weights('model_0_weights.h5')
m1 = init_binary_classification_model(input_shape)
m1.load_weights('model_1_weights.h5')
m2 = init_binary_classification_model(input_shape)
m2.load_weights('model_2_weights.h5')

Construct New Multiclassification Models
from keras.layers import Softmax, Concatenate

input_layer = Input(shape=(28,28))

output_0 = m0(input_layer)
output_1 = m1(input_layer)
output_2 = m2(input_layer)

concat_output = Concatenate()([output_0, output_1, output_2])

final_output = Softmax()(concat_output)

final_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=final_output)

